# Partitioning errors when attempting to install 22.04 on a HP Elitebook 840 G3

Tags: partitioning, ssd, hp

I am trying to install Ubuntu 22.04 LTS an a HP EliteBook 840 G3. I have formatted the SSD to bare metal.

I can boot from my thumb drive and start the installer, but I error out at the screen where I would select my timezone, but I am interrupted by an error message referring to a partitioning problem.

Might someone be able to point me to any known problems with partitioning on this machine? I have been reading web posts for the afternoon, and I am at a dead end.

But, I have seen a couple of questions here that indicate this installation is possible.

Is it even possible to Install Ubuntu on an HP Elitebook 840 G3 to replaces Windows 10 on a cleanly formatted SSD?

If anyone is feeling charitable and willing to give me some ideas on what to attack, and how to go about it?

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the exact text of the error message(s) you are getting? Avoid paraphrasing in your own words because we likely won't recognize the error. Also, it's very helpful if you would share your research as well as the details of any attempts you've already taken. This can be valuable information. Unfortunately, telling us you searched without sharing any of the research doesn't really provide any information we can use to help answer your question.

Comment: If the drive is freshly formatted and you are using the recommended settings, you shouldn't be getting any errors about partitioning. I suggest you start over.  First [verify the ISO you downloaded](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/how-to-verify-ubuntu). If your installation media is invalid, you could try and fail a million times. Then, follow along with the [official tutorial](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop). If you're still stuck, reference the tutorial when asking so we know exactly where you're stuck.

Comment: found this in my notes: HP Elitebook 840 G5 gpt issues - 
HP put a fail-safe gpt recovery into the UEFI Settings,  go into the UEFI Menu in Security -> Hard Drive Utilities -> Uncheck "Save/restore GPT System of Hard Drive"
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2436271